# HTML input date field, how to set default value to today's date?

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I'm slightly confused as to why my JS script isn't working, I have set it up to populate the date field to today's date, but the HTML date picker is still showing dd/mm/yyyy by default.

my HTML is:

```
<div class="col">
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="date" onload="getDate()" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
</div>
```

my JS is:

```
function getDate(){
var today = new Date();

document.getElementById("date").value = today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);

}
```

```js
function getDate(){
var today = new Date();

document.getElementById("date").value = today.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);

}
```

```html
 <div class="col">
           <label for="date">Date</label>
           <input type="date" onload="getDate()" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For input elements, the onload attribute is only supported when `<input type="image">`

**Tip:**
You use `DOMContentLoaded` for setting the default value

```js
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        document.getElementById("date").valueAsDate = new Date();
    });
</script>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with that as well. I arrived at:

document.getElementById('mydate').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);

Comment: That returns the UTC date, which might be ±1 day depending on the host timezone and when the code is run.